# Method not being called, no error, maybe has to do with generics/companion objects/inheritance/concurrency/inlining

Tags: kotlin

Okay, so I have a class called ChannelBase which is the superclass for all channel-type things in Slack (basically just Channels and Groups as MPIMs aren't considered groups anymore)

Within ChannelBase there is an `abstract class ChannelCompanion<T : BaseChannel<T>>` (the generic is the type of the subclass, aka `Channel` or `Group`). The subclass then has its companion object extend ChannelCompanion, which forces it to have a `fromJson(JsonObject)` function, and provides the companion object with a `inline fun start(callback: () -> Unit)` that gathers the channel list from the Slack API and parses it.

So basically here's what we have, let's assume we're registering the `Channel` class.
When `Channel.start { }` (inherited from ChannelCompanion) is called, here is what should happen:

-> Call `ChannelCompanion.start {  }`
-> Asynchronously make HTTP request to a slack team's channels.list method
-> Parse the JSON and retrieve the array of Channel JsonObjects
-> Parse each JsonObject into a Channel object using  `Channel.fromJson(JsonObject)` (an abstract fun in ChannelCompanion)

The problem is that when `Channel.fromJson` gets called, the Thread freezes. There is no error or exception, it just freezes. If you don't understand the structure of this (it's hard to explain), here is the repository: https://github.com/Deanveloper/SlaK/tree/master/src/main/kotlin/com/deanveloper/slak/channel

Debug code shows that the program freezes when `Channel.fromJson` is called. The first line of `Channel.fromJson` is to print that the function was run, and it doesn't print. The line before it gets called is printed, though. Not quite sure what's going on here.

It is good to note that while there are multiple threads, this is all executed in the same thread after the HTTP request is made.

If you want to clone the repository and test for yourself, https://github.com/Deanveloper/SlaK. In the JUnit test directory, go to BaseTest and replace the encrypted API key with an API key for a Slack team of your own

Comment: Are you sure there is no exception when Channel.fromJson invoke?

Comment: @Yrgl Yes. Again, the line before I call Channel.fromJson I print something successfully, and the very first line of the fromJson function is to print something, which doesn't run successfully. Also I don't ever ignore exceptions, so any exception should print.

Comment: @Deanveloper, threads don't print uncaught exceptions by default. To be completely sure please check that `uncaughtExceptionHandler` is set for the thread.

Comment: @hotkey will do as soon as I have access to a computer again!

Comment: @hotkey Nope, no exception being thrown from what it looks like.

Comment: @hotkey I was using a cached thread pool to generate the threads, so I guess that caught the exception. I surrounded it with try/catch and it threw IllegalAccessErrors as the method is protected, and the function is inlined so it was called from outside the package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was caused by inlining, as the function fromJson has a protected scope. Because the function was inlined, the fromJson function was actually being called from outside the package (as the start method was called from outside the package). This caused an IllegalAccessError.